# RegEx - get count of elements which are not wrapped

Tags: php, regex

For example I have a string like this:

```
first:second:third"test:test":fourth
```

I want to count the ':' and later to split every ':' to get the strings.

This is my regex:

```
/(.*):(.*)/iU
```

I don't know if this is the best solution, but it works. There is a different between a '.' and a "[...] : [...]" so I need to seperate them. I realized that my regex counts the : but continues when the : is between ".

I tried to solve this with this regex:

```
/(((.*)[^"]):((.*)[^"]))/iU
```

I thought this is the right way, but it isn't. I tried to learn the regex syntax, but I don't understand this problem.

This regex just means:
search for ':' - every think can be infornt and after it EXCEPT wehen a " is in front of it AND a " is after it.

Maybe you can help me.

edit: I use my regex in PHP - maybe this is an important information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using

```
$result = preg_split(
    '/:       # Match a colon
    (?=       # only if followed by
     (?:      # the following group:
      [^"]*"  #  Any number of characters except ", followed by one "
      [^"]*"  #  twice in a row (to ensure even number of "s)
     )*       # (repeated zero or more times)
     [^"]*    # followed by any number of non-quotes until...
     $        # the end of the string.
    )         # End of lookahead assertion
    /x', 
    $subject);
```

which will give you the result

```
first
second
third"test:test"
fourth
```

directly?

This regex splits on a `:` only if it's followed by an even number of quotes. This means that it won't split on a `:` inside a string:

Comment: Thank you! I will work with your regex and try to learn why your regex does what it does ;)

Comment: @TimoRütten: I have converted it to a verbose regex. Hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Yes it is! Very helpful! Thank you - i ll look forward to understand the syntax and learning by doing! Thanks Tim!

Comment: I have tested your regex again - and the count of matches are right. Also the postion of the strings it founds are right - but it returns with preg_match_all just the ':' - but important is to get the strings between the ':' - maybe you can tell me how to change the return value in the regex ? When i read your regex with your comments in it it seems like that your regex have to return the strings - but it does not ...

Comment: @TimoRütten: The regex is designed to match the delimiters (colons) *between*  the matches, that's why you need to use it with `preg_split()` instead of `preg_match_all()`. After all, the way I understand it, your final goal is to split the string, isn't it?

Comment: Yes - the final goal is to split it - but with regex. I also can develope a script that will split the string with default functions of PHP in the right way - but i need to learn regex. But Yes - the final goal is just to split the strings - and your're right - i can do it with preg_split. Thanks for your help, Tim! ... Und entschuldige mein miserables Englisch ... *grins

Answer (score 2):

This regex should do it, if it match your needs and you want additional explanation, just ask :)

```
(?<=:|^)(?<!"[^:][^"]+:)\w+?(?=:|"|$)
```

That's the test string I used

> "test1:test2:test3":first:second:third"test1:test2:test3":fourth:fifth"test1:test2:test3":sixth

And these are 6 following matches:

```
first
second
third
fourth
fifth
sixth
```

Answer (score 0):

I love parsing text. So I write a parser for you.

```
$sample = 'first:second:third"test:test":fourth';
$len = strlen($sample);
$c =0;
$buffer="";
$output = array();
$instr = false;
for($i =0; $i< $len; $i++){
    if($sample[$i]=='"' or $sample[$i]=="'"){
        $c++;
        $instr= $c%2==0 ? false: true;
        $buffer.=$sample[$i];
    }elseif(!$instr and $sample[$i]==':'){
        $output[]=$buffer;
        $buffer = "";
    }else{
        $buffer.=$sample[$i];
    }
}
if($buffer) $output[] = $buffer;

print_r($output);
```

See the [code in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/sAIXYm). Also note for huge string regular expression will perform poor.